# Cannot install Wine, error message is not descriptive of the problem

Tags: package-management, software-installation, 15.04, wine

When I try to install wine, this happens:

```
sudo apt-get install wine
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package wine is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'wine' has no installation candidate
```

This does not make sense to me, as I am running Ubuntu 15.04 Vivid and have seen it loud and clear on [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/wine).

The contents of `etc/apt/sources.list` are as follows:

```
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ vivid main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ vivid main restricted multiverse

deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ vivid-updates main restricted universe   multiverse
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ vivid-updates main restricted universe multiverse

 deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ vivid-security main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://ports.ubuntu.com/ vivid-security main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ vivid-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/ vivid main universe restricted multiverse
```

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get update` and try again.

Comment: You need to add the universe repository - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

Comment: @bodhi.zazen It is always there by default. If `update` does not help, then it must be some internet problem, like proxy.

Comment: @Pilot6 - Universe may be enabled by default, it can be disabled either at the time of installation or afterwards. if the package is no found it is usually due to a repository problem.

Comment: @Pilot6 I have verified that it is not an internet problem.

Comment: Could you post the contents of `/apt/sources.list`? Maybe that file has become corrupt.

Comment: @BlackMage The comment box will not accept it, so I will edit my original post to reflect it.

Answer (score 2):

Wine is on the Universe repository, which should be enabled by default. Check if it is through Software & Updates > Ubuntu software > Community-mantained free and open-source software (universe). If it's not, tick the box.

Afterwards run `sudo apt-get update` and you can install wine.

Alternatively, there is also a PPA avaiable containg the latest unstable version. To install this, execute the following command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
```

Run `sudo apt-get update` again afterwards.

After doing either of these two just execute `sudo apt-get install wine`to install wine.

Comment: `wine` is not in partner.

Comment: It is `Package: wine (1:1.6.2-0ubuntu8) [universe]` from the packages page.

Comment: So why do you recommend to enable "Canonical partners"? It is irrelevant.

Comment: I just changed my answer to correctly reflect this.

Comment: Now it is good, but I suspect that the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @Pilot6 You may be right. I haven't had a chance to try the first thing yet but I already have the PPA and that *still* didn't work.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: @BlackMage  Okay, first:  I tried this, and it was *not* checked. Thank you for your answer, but it still didn't work. From an optimistic point of view, you have eliminated one possibility. If anybody else has an idea, that would be great.

Comment: @Pilot6 Second:  I am not behind a proxy, and based on the status page during 'apt-get update' I am hitting the Universe repository without obstruction. Also, in the Software Center, I can search for Wine and find it, but the install button does not appear and clicking the "more info" button leads to a "package not found" eror message.

Comment: What does `apt-cache policy wine` show?